# Setting scope data from asynchronous code in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning AngularJs. I have a simple controller:

```
angular.module('test').controller('RouteFinderController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.startSystem = { systemName: "Test" }
});
```

this works as intended - the view can make use of the `startSystem` field.

However, if I make a slight change:

```
angular.module('test').controller('RouteFinderController', function ($scope) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $scope.startSystem = { systemName: "Test" }
    },0);
});
```

It no longer works! I can't access the `startSystem` field anymore.

Why is this, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Use built-in Angular services, like `$timeout` (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) instead of `setTimeout` - otherwise Angular doesn't know the scope changed and that it needs to update the view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://coderwall.com/p/udpmtq) Should answer your question, you have to use `$scope.$apply()` if you're using `setTimeout()` but as seen here, using `$timeout()` is recommended.

Comment: Great, thanks. I didn't know that `$scope.$apply()` was required. the `setTimeout` in my question was just the simpler form of my real problem, which came up when I was trying to load `JSON` data asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS is not aware of the change you made. To apply them you could use

```
angular.module('test').controller('RouteFinderController', function ($scope) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $scope.startSystem = { systemName: "Test" }
    },0);
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

But as [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) already does that for you, it is much easier to simply use it instead:

```
angular.module('test').controller('RouteFinderController', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.startSystem = { systemName: "Test" }
    },0);
});
```